# Passing values from collection to view

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform

Hi here is a backbonejs / Parse.com code that tries to get list of firstNames from a class in Parse. The goal is to have the view "pluck" function correctly access data pulled from database.

Here is the model:

```
var Subscribers = Parse.Object.extend({
    className: "Subscribers"

});
```

Here is the collection that correctly does its job when I hardcode objects instances. Of course I don't want to have the firstNames hardcoded here but pulled from Parse.com backend. How should I replace this code to have the data correctly pulled from server ? Should I use a fetch ? I tried but unsucessfully.

```
var DoopizCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({
        model: Subscribers
    }
);

//var doopizlist = new DoopizCollection([
//    {firstName: "bob"},      //hardcoded instances : this works.
//    {firstName : "luke"} ]);
var doopizlist = new DoopizCollection();
doopizlist .fetch({
  success: function(doopizlist ) {
    collection.each(function(object) {
      console.warn(object);
    });
  },
  error: function(doopizlist , error) {
    console.log("error")
  }
});
```

And here is the view:

```
var DoopizView = Parse.View.extend({
    el: '#container',

    render: function() {
        var html = '';
        html = this.collection.pluck('firstName');
        $(this.el).html(html);
    }
});

var doopizView = new DoopizView({
    collection: doopizlist
});

doopizView.render();
```

Comment: how do you use the fetch? and what response do you get?

Comment: I use fetch with success/ error because it's async, but i'm not sure what to put in case of success.

Comment: so you mean the pull from parse.com will return success but without data? can you use chrome developer console to debug and post the return request headers and body here?

Comment: Please see code I updated it with the fetch code. the pluck then logs object Object.

Comment: what is `TestCollection`? and after fetching from `doopizlist`, why you iterate through `TestCollection`? you should just iterate through `doopizlist` to get the updated models.

Comment: Sorry I did posted a bad code. I updated it, of course, it is an iteration through doopizlist, please see revised code.

Comment: I don't see the correction is done correctly. You should do something like this https://gist.github.com/coderek/7410099